# Automatically build C project with CMake in VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cmake, makefile

First some context, I haven't programmed in C for more than 10 years, but now I have a side project I'd like to do.
I used to code in MS Visual Studio or on Linux with Code::Block, the beauty of it was I didn't bother how to build, it just builds, so I could focus on my code.

No I want to use VSCode, because that's my nr.1 IDE to do JavaScript projects and other stuff. I can compile a simple C file, but a more complex project with more c/h files failed for me. Than I tried all kind of extensions like Make, CMake, ... with no success.

I wasted a day on this, so I hope you can help me with the following project structure:

```
project_folder
        |
        -- main.c
        |
        -- src/
        |   |
            -- engine.c
        |
        -- include/
        |       |
        |       --core/
        |           |
        |           -- engine.h


main.c:
-----------
#include <core/engine.h>

int main() {
        ...
        ...
}
```

When I try to compile, it can't find <core/engine.h>, I was hoping CMake scans all the folders and figure things out itself, but that's not the case.
I use Linux (Ubuntu) and I rather use CMake as the build tool.
I really hope you can help me on this.

Comment: Show the `CMakeLists.txt` you wrote for this.

Comment: ***I was hoping CMake scans all the folders and figure things out itself*** No it does no scanning on it's own. You can use file globbing in your CMakeLists.txt if you want. The developers used to recommend not doing that and instead list each file in the CMakeLists.txt directly. For example / test projects I use file globbing. For production code I list every single file even on code with several hundred source files.

Comment: ***but a more complex project with more c/h files failed for me*** In the default build method without the CMakeTools or Makefile tools extension VSCode builds only the active file. The documentation states this default behavior and tells you how to change it: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson) if you use a different OS the docs all have a modifying tasks.json section with basically the same instruruction.

Comment: "First some context ..." - That context (how long you have not programming, how do you like Visual Studio for its JavaScript support and so on) absolutely doesn't help to understand your problem: that context describes you instead of the problem. On Stack Overflow we tend to omit such "context".

Comment: Yes, it tells about me, that after such a long time I may missed some new developments that make building C/C++ based projects much easier without the need to tell the compiler exactly what to do, without reading tens of pages just to build a relatively simple project. SO needs perfect questions with perfect answers so their AI can train better and you help them, good for you.

Comment: @AndaluZ "have I the perfect solution for you"  sorry for the shameless plug, but I developed a VSCode extension that does exactly what you are looking for. [C Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit) can create C projects having as many files and folders as you want, with boilerplate code. And it provides buttons for building, running and debugging. And it based on CMake so you can customize it in any way you want or even ditrch the extension after creating the project. Naturally it works on all platforms too, and installs all missing tools. :)

Answer (score 4):

lets ignore vscode for a second here. if you have a working cmake project you can work backwards from that and import it into vscode.

under your folder `project_folder` you should have created a `CMakeLists.txt` file. in this file you should have something that resembles

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(c_solution C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(c_solution
        src/engine.c
        main.c)
target_include_directories(c_solution PRIVATE include)
```

or something equivalent to that.

given you are in the `project_folder` you then should be able to run

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

and a executable binary should be in your `project_folder/build` folder.

from here you can import your solution into vscode and use their plugin. it will plug into the already created cmake project.

That said I would highly recommend into looking into how to [cmake as a build tool outside of vscode](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/), as it is just one ide and cmake is a standalone build tool.